# Questions regarding development of a content management and file sharing app using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am pretty new to ruby and am currently trying to develop a web app using rails. 
The application is one where users can create groups, upload and share files in this group and can have group forums just like a group chat. I have used devise for creating users model. Is there any gem that i can use to create groups?
I intend to use paperclip for uploading of files. I really need all the suggestions and help i can get.

Answer (score -1):

This is very much off topic as its not a code based question.

You could have a look at https://github.com/scaffeinate/socify this is a RoR built social network.

Comment: Can you please help me with where i can look for help? anyone who can help me with some Q/A

Comment: I googled around and i cant find much. but in my personal opinion you might be better off building a custom solution (Using scaffolds) and that will also give you more experience in the matter.